# Celery, create subtask from within task: received unregistered task of type

Tags: celery, django-celery

Using django-celery, I'm trying to create some sub tasks from within a main task but am getting this error: received unregistered task of type 'smallTask'.

Any idea what's wrong please?  And if this is the right way to create sub tasks in this way?

Thanks,

```
@task
def mainTask():
    count = 0
    logger = mainTask.get_logger()
    logger.info('LOGGER: in main task')

    while count < 10:
        subtask('smallTask', args=(count), countdown=0).apply_async()
        count += 1

@task
def smallTask():
    logger = smallTask.get_logger()
    logger.info('LOGGER: in main task')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure if this is the best way to do this, but with some additional help on SO from another question, I have this working now.

```
@task
def mainTask():
    count = 0
    logger = mainTask.get_logger()
    logger.info('LOGGER: in main task')
    obj = {'foo':'bar'}
    while count < 10:
        subtask('smallTask', args=(obj,)).apply_async()
        count += 1

@task(name='smallTask')
def smallTask():
    logger = smallTask.get_logger()
    logger.info('LOGGER: in sub task')
```